# Python video processing libraries?

Tags: python, video

Are there python libraries for processing video?  In particular:

- identify codec used
- create a lower-quality preview of a video
- add a watermark to a video

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See [Hachoir](http://hachoir3.readthedocs.io/) and [MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html).

1. identify codec used

   - **Hachoir**: [extract metadata](http://hachoir3.readthedocs.io/metadata.html#example)
2. create a lower-quality preview of a video

   - **MoviePy**: use [resize function](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx/moviepy.video.fx.all.resize.html)
3. add a watermark to a video

   - **MoviePy**: you will need to create an `ImageClip` for the watermark then overlay it on the desired video with `CompositeVideoClip`.